# Error setting ZNC start at boot on Raspberry

Tags: boot

I'm trying to start ZNC on my Raspberry at boot. I followed step by step [this](https://wiki.znc.in/Running_ZNC_as_a_system_daemon) official guide creating the /etc/init.d/azn script

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          znc
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: ZNC IRC bouncer
# Description:       ZNC is an IRC bouncer
### END INIT INFO
 
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="ZNC daemon"
NAME=znc
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
DATADIR=/var/lib/znc
DAEMON_ARGS="--datadir=$DATADIR"
PIDDIR=/var/run/znc
PIDFILE=$PIDDIR/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
USER=znc
GROUP=znc

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14) to ensure that this file is present
# and status_of_proc is working.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    if [ ! -d $PIDDIR ]
    then
        mkdir $PIDDIR
    fi
    chown $USER:$GROUP $PIDDIR
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test --chuid $USER > /dev/null || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --chuid $USER -- $DAEMON_ARGS > /dev/null || return 2
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME --chuid $USER
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON --chuid $USER
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME --chuid $USER
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_reload
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  restart)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {status|start|stop|reload|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

but I'm getting the following errors:

```
andrea@nameless23:~ $ sudo service znc start
Job for znc.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status znc.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.



andrea@nameless23:~ $ systemctl status znc.service
● znc.service - LSB: ZNC IRC bouncer
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/znc; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-04-05 12:03:13 CEST; 20s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 12197 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/znc start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: ZNC IRC bouncer...
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[12197]: znc.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[12197]: znc.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/znc: No such file or directory
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[1]: znc.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[1]: znc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: ZNC IRC bouncer.



andrea@nameless23:~ $ journalctl -xe
Apr 05 11:59:01 nameless23 CRON[11981]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/omv-ionice >/dev/null 2>&1)
Apr 05 11:59:01 nameless23 CRON[11980]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 05 11:59:14 nameless23 sudo[11988]:   andrea : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/andrea ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/init.d/znc
Apr 05 11:59:14 nameless23 sudo[11988]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by andrea(uid=0)
Apr 05 12:00:01 nameless23 CRON[11999]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 05 12:00:01 nameless23 CRON[11998]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 05 12:00:01 nameless23 CRON[12000]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/omv-mkrrdgraph >/dev/null 2>&1)
Apr 05 12:00:01 nameless23 CRON[12001]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/omv-ionice >/dev/null 2>&1)
Apr 05 12:00:01 nameless23 CRON[11999]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 05 12:00:09 nameless23 CRON[11998]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 05 12:00:28 nameless23 sudo[11988]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 05 12:01:01 nameless23 CRON[12124]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 05 12:01:01 nameless23 CRON[12125]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/omv-ionice >/dev/null 2>&1)
Apr 05 12:01:01 nameless23 CRON[12124]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 05 12:02:01 nameless23 CRON[12144]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 05 12:02:01 nameless23 CRON[12145]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/omv-ionice >/dev/null 2>&1)
Apr 05 12:02:01 nameless23 CRON[12144]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 05 12:03:01 nameless23 CRON[12163]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 05 12:03:01 nameless23 CRON[12164]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/omv-ionice >/dev/null 2>&1)
Apr 05 12:03:01 nameless23 CRON[12163]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 05 12:03:08 nameless23 sudo[12171]:   andrea : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/andrea ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service znc start
Apr 05 12:03:08 nameless23 sudo[12171]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by andrea(uid=0)
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: ZNC IRC bouncer...
-- Subject: A start job for unit znc.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit znc.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 7548.
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[12197]: znc.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[12197]: znc.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/znc: No such file or directory
-- Subject: Process /etc/init.d/znc could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The process /etc/init.d/znc could not be executed and failed.
--
-- The error number returned by this process is ERRNO.
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[1]: znc.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit znc.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 203.
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[1]: znc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The unit znc.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: ZNC IRC bouncer.
-- Subject: A start job for unit znc.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit znc.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 7548 and the job result is failed.
Apr 05 12:03:13 nameless23 sudo[12171]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Why I get `No such file or directory` error?

Comment: You haven't explained what ZNC is or does. Listing an obsolete SysV script is unlikely to encourage answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your `--datadir` value needs to be `/var/lib/znc/.znc` (`.znc` at the end)